# How to Turkify the values in a JSON file?

Tags: localization

Good forums,

I'm machine translating a game for my own use, but I only need to translate the values in the JSON file, normally when I translate the JSON file, the titles are translated and the patch breaks. How can I do this? For example, I only need to translate the fields I have marked in red below and there are thousands of these lines. I need to somehow extract them in these headers, translate them and put them back. How can I do that, is there a tool for that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxuZv.png)

I cannot translate values in json files.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at a localization tool like the Okapi Framework (open-source). It can help you extract the localizable strings into an easily translatable format and also supports MT.
https://www.okapiframework.org/